# Make bower work with npm using browserify

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, commonjs, browserify

We are both blessed and cursed by a plethora of package management solutions for JavaScript, all with their respective merits.  For reasons that are irrelevant here, I have settled on npm for my primary solution.  However, there is too much good code out there on other systems like bower and component to ignore these solutions. So, I am looking to set up an environment where I can use browserify to load packages from both npm and bower (we'll save component for another question).

The best I came up with so far was to setup my `package.json` with a `postinstall` script that runs `bower install`:

```
{
  ... configuration ...

  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  }
}
```

This builds the correct directory structure when installing first-level dependencies (i.e. strait bower dependencies and strait npm dependencies):

```
- MyMixedComponent
  - main.js
  - package.json
  - node_modules
    - npmDependency
  - bower_components
    - bowerComponent
```

Which builds fine using the [debowerify](https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify) transform on browserify, `browserify -t debowerify`   However, when I want to then install MyMixedComponent from npm in another project, `npm install MyMixedComponent`, the directory structure is built as you would expect from npm:

```
- MyNewProject
  - main.js
  - package.json
  - node_modules
    - MyMixedComponent
      - main.js
      - package.json
      - node_modules
        - npmDependency
      - bower_components
        - bowerComponent
```

Since bower is a flat dependency tree, this of course does not work when trying to build with browserify and debowerify. Whats actually needed is something like this:

```
- MyNewProject
  - main.js
  - package.json
  - node_modules
    - MyMixedComponent
      - main.js
      - package.json
      - node_modules
        - npmDependency
   - bower_components
     - bowerComponent
```

Alternatively debowerify could be modified to recognize multiple bower directories, but that would defeat the lovely characteristic of bower that it is a flat tree, which is much better for front end dependencies.  Any thoughts about how this could work, or should I just pray that we all someday agree on dependency management?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS RequireJS Browserify and the Javascript module/global scope nightmare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987634/angularjs-requirejs-browserify-and-the-javascript-module-global-scope-nightmare)

Comment: @PaulSweatte The question you referenced deals with conflicts between best practices of Angular and the AMD/CommonJS module paradigm. This question is aimed at rectifying the conflicting structures of package management systems; one hierarchical (npm) and one flat (bower). My objective is to utilize both systems within projects while maintaining modularity. i.e. dependencies load correctly when a project is treated as a stand-alone or a library.

Comment: In that case, [this idea](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) may work for you.

Comment: @PaulSweatte thanks for sending along the article but again it doesn't quite address the problem.  The problem is with the way dependencies are handled with different package management solutions such as npm and bower.  AMD vs CommonJS is irrelevant since these package management systems can be used with either. I'm editing the question to try to make that more clear.

Comment: A combination of [npm-explore](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-explore.html) and [npm-link](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html) would allow you to have a flat structure and a tree structure.

Comment: Have you tried using "napa" with browserify to access bower packages? And, yeah, I didn't quite get what you are asking for but it seems like the tool to use in that domain.

Comment: [napa](https://github.com/shama/napa) looks like a decent solution to the problem of supporting modules that don't support npm. The weakness I see with it is installing the dependencies of the modules imported using napa.  For instance, we might end up writing a messy little script like`napa username/repo-with-bower; cd node_modules/repo-with-bower; bower install;`.

Comment: Why not use both and automate with `grunt`?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of having multiple bower_components in the same codebase, has the risk of introducing duplicates of some particular framework.

Try going down the road of :

1. When installing an mixed (npm and bower) package into my current package,
2. Install npm as usual (nested),
3. And for-each bower-component from mixed-package `bower install` into root of current package
4. An [interactive npm postinstall script](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html), could just alter the bower.json of the current package
5. And warn the user to do a bower install, since bower.json is now updated with the components from your other npm/bower mixed package

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to avoid modifying the bower.json for the root package since that is likely under version control. Perhaps simply running `bower install <package>` for every nested dependency. Still would get duplicate code for nested packages that are looking in their own bower_components directory : /